# regex - Replace multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, apache-spark-sql, impala

I have a string, Can be any of the below cases:

1. test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/
2. test1/test2/test3/test4//
3. test1/test2/test3///
4. test1/test2////
5. test1/////

My expected results are

1. test1/test2/test3/test4/test5
2. test1/test2/test3/test4
3. test1/test2/test3
4. test1/test2
5. test1
   How can i achieve using regex ?

Currently, i am using regexp_replace(col, "/+/", "/") it is working but leaving an extra / on the end.

Comment: Split at `/`, filter out empty strings from the array, join with `/`.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654661/3832970) help?

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
regexp_replace(col, '/+$|(/){2,}', '\\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zp5GLR/2).

**Details**

- `/+$` - 1 or more `/` at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `(/){2,}` - two or more slashes, the last of which will be saved in Capturing group 1 that you will be able to refer to from the replacement pattern using the `\1` placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
/\/+$/gm
```

and replace with an empty string (`''`).

The regex will match one or more slashes in the end of the string, then will replace those with the empty string, meaning the paths will no longer end in a slash.